# CSS Transforms giving divs an outline

Tags: html, css, transform, gradient, isometric

Im building an isometric grid of cubes created with css but im running into an issue with outlines.

Heres what I would like to achieve:
[cube design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kosjw.png)
But heres what i've got so far:

[html cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQzJG.png)
I've tried the usual tricks like using some translateZ and backface visibility but to no avail.

My css is looking like this:

.cube {

```
transform: rotateX(55deg) rotateZ(45deg) translateX(50%) translateY(-50%);
transform-origin: 0% 0%;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
position: relative;
pointer-events:all;
transition: background-position ease 7s;
background-size: 400% 400%;


div {
  position: absolute;
  transition: background-position ease 7s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

  &:first-child {
    transform-origin: center top;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    top: 100%;
  }

  &:nth-child(2) {
    transform-origin: left center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
  }
}
```

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/jaketh9000/pen/JerbVY)

Comment: I got it somewhat close to what you want, if you are happy I can post it as an acceptable answer. Check here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mQBWOo#anon-signup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here would be to have the faces of the cubes to overlap and use the `background-blend-mode` CSS attribute to have them blend into each other. That causes the cubes to blend into each other and get rid of the weird borders.

Working codepen link here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXzWjJ

You might need to play around with the transforms and dimensions a bit to get the exact result you want.

It's not the best solution but it seems to work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wicked! Thanks for this!

Comment: No worries. Please do upvote and Mark as selected answer if it worked for you. Cheers!